# Laravel 5 on shared hosting - wrong public_path()

Tags: php, laravel-5, shared-hosting

I deployed a Laravel 5 project to a shared hosting account, placing the app-files outside of the www-folder, placing only the public folder inside of the www-folder. All like explained here, in the best answer: [Laravel 4 and the way to deploy app using FTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22023048/laravel-4-and-the-way-to-deploy-app-using-ftp)... without 3. because this file doesn't exist in Laravel 5.

Now when I call public_path() inside of a controller i get something like ***my-appfiles-outside-of-www*/public** instead of **www/public**. Does anyone know why I doesn't get the right path here? Can I change this somewhere?
Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can override public_path using container.
Example:

```
App::bind('path.public', function() {
    return base_path().'/public_html';
});
```

Comment: Service proivder is better way to do that, i think

Comment: Which file above code to be placed, please post the complete solution

Comment: I tried to place the code into AppServiceProvider Class, but it doesn't work

Comment: @Marwan: The solution I'm using now is this one: [https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/where-do-you-set-public-directory-laravel-5](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/where-do-you-set-public-directory-laravel-5)  (see the "best answer" from DoubleD)

Answer (score 4):

```
$app->bind('path.public', function() {
  return __DIR__;
});
```

write above code in public_html\index.php above of this code

```
$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of solutions, like a change to index.php or the accepted one with the ioc container.

The solution that works best, in my opinion, is described in this SO question:
[Laravel 5 change public_path()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31758901/laravel-5-change-public-path)

Why is it better than other solutions? Because it works for regular http request, use of artisan ánd use of phpunit for testing! E.g. the change to index.php works only for http requests but leads to failures when using PHPunit (in my case: *file (...) not defined in asset manifest*).

A short recap of that solution:
Step 1: In the file: bootstrap/app.php change the very first declaration of $app variable from:

```
$app = new Illuminate\Foundation\Application(
    realpath(__DIR__.'/../')
);
```

to:

```
$app = new App\Application(
    realpath(__DIR__.'/../')
);
```

This points to your own custom Application class, which we will create in step 2.

Step 2: Create the file Application.php in the app folder:

```
<?php namespace App;

class Application extends \Illuminate\Foundation\Application
{
   public function publicPath()
   {
       return $this->basePath . '/../public_html';
   }
}
```

Be sure to change the path to your needs. The example assumes a directory structure like so:
°°laravel_app
°°°°app
°°°°bootstrap
°°°°config
°°°°...
°°public_html

In case of the OP, the path should probably be

```
return $this->basePath . '/../www/public';
```

(up one from laravel_app, then down into www/public)