# Will there be any issue if I redirect laravel project root path to public directory?

Tags: php, laravel, web-deployment, shared-hosting

I want to deploy the Laravel project to my shared hosting.

When I go to my site main domain (example.com) It displays all directory and files but (example.com/public) works fine.

What if I just create an `index.php` file in the project root directory with following code

```
<?php
header('Location: ./public');
?>
```

It just redirects me to `example.com/public`.

Just tell me if there will be an issue that may occur at any point?
I am new to Laravel.

I don't care to remove the public directory. I only care if someone goes to `example.com` then it just redirects `example.com/public` to work fine.

---

**Update**

Just keep it short and simple answer (Yes/No) then explain it.

Is there will be an issue that occurs with the above steps (actions)? **(Yes/No)**

Comment: try to change your Laravel app's base directory.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set the base path in Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31805814/how-to-set-the-base-path-in-laravel-5)

Comment: Probably this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35461322/upload-laravel-5-to-server-subfolder/35474800#35474800

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for comments and answers but those are not relevant to my question. I have updated (added) two more lines to keep the answer short and simple. Thanks again. I hope you will understand.

Answer (score 0):

did you point your vhost to to the public directory?

For Apache

```
DocumentRoot [Laravel root direcoty]/public
```

For Nginx

```
root [Laravel root direcoty]/public;
```

[Laravel Deploment](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/deployment)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest the easy way, by create a symbolic link of public_html and link it to your laravel project's public directory. don't forget to set your project folder permission.

here's the example: https://blog.netgloo.com/2016/01/29/deploy-laravel-application-on-shared-hosting/