# Laravel 5.x - Problem with load image and upload or moving file on shared hosting

Tags: laravel, upload, cpanel, move, filepath

I've been following this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29892024/laravel-5-on-shared-hosting-wrong-public-path)

But, so far it is not enough to solve my problems, I want to ask the best practice or solution to be applied for this problem

this is my controller code:

```
  if($request->hasfile('news_photo_url'))
    {

           $image = $request->file('news_photo_url');
           $name=$image->getClientOriginalName();
           $image_path = public_path().'\\img\\news';
           $image_path_to_db = '\\img\\news\\'.$name;
           $image->move($image_path,$name);
    }
```

and this is how I load image,

```
<img src="{{ asset($news->news_photo_url) }}" alt="">
```

and this is perfectly fine on my local,

but things is different in shared hosting cpanel, my app is located here

```
home/laravel/
```

and my public (index.php) is located here

```
home/public_html/name/
```

how to work this out properly ?

since add this line of code also didn't work,

```
$app->bind('path.public', function() {return __DIR__; });
```

since this simply tells the public is here, but the path stored in db and will be different

```
http://xxx.xxx.com/home/user/public_html/afe1f78ef6233580f2739a69be00027f.jpg
```

thank you before

Comment: btw, I've also attempt to modify the path for controller, but it doesn't help either :(

Comment: hmmm... I am not sure I get the whole picture of your question. But I think one things you seem to be using wrong is your asset helper. `src="{{ asset($news->news_photo_url) }}" ` should be something like `src="{{ asset('/img/news/' . $news->news_photo_url) }}"` based on your controller.

Comment: apologize, it is quite hard  to actually explain it myself, 
I mean, 
does this happen all the time? this might be out of topic but laravel app folder in shared hosting should not be located in public_html right?

Comment: I want to avoid modify that asset helper ..
I tried modify this too
```$app->bind('path.public', function() {return __DIR__; });```
to ```$app->bind('path.public', function() {return __DIR__.'img/news'; });```

but instead of moving the files to that folder, it create another folder name "img/news"

Comment: well I think the most common place to put your public folder is as intended in the framework which is in the root of your proyect, but you should still be able to place it somewhere else, I would suggest you look into configuring your asset url, you can look at this configuration in the `app.php` file or add it in you .env with the name `ASSET_URL`

Comment: I see, thank you for your help, I will try as you suggest, do you mind putting your comment to the answer, I will accept your answer

Comment: there it is, hope it helps, let me know if you where able to solve your problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can modify the location of your assets by either modifying your `app.php` file or I think even better adding a variable to your .env to set the location of your assets depending if they differ in local and production.

`app.php`

```
'asset_url' => env('ASSET_URL', null),
```

or

`.env`

```
ASSET_URL=path/to/folder
```